# Able to view a PartialView when accessed directly, but not with HTML.Partiaul

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a partial view like this, which should give me all of the related records for a request:

```
public ActionResult DetailsList(short? id)
        {
            var requestDetails = db.RequestDetails.Where(i => i.RequestID == id);
            return View(requestDetails.ToList());

        }
```

Which when accessed loads all of the records for a particular ID (in this case, Request number 24)

[image]

I'm trying to embed this as a partial view to appear on my main Requests page, like so:

```
@model CollectionMGR.Models.Request

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Collection Creation Request Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Request Overview</h4>
    <hr /><p>You can view detailed info about your request here</p>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AppName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PackageName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PackageName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Action)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Action)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CollectionID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CollectionID)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Computers)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Computers)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Disposed)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Disposed)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.RequestID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

    <h3>@ViewBag.DetailStatus</h3>

    @if (ViewBag.DetailStatus == "No detailed records found")
    {
    <p>no stuff to show</p>
}
else
{
    <p>would be displaying stuff here</p>


    <div>
        <p><i>Start of Partial View</i></p>
        @Html.Partial("../RequestDetails/DetailsList", Model.RequestID)
        <p><i>End of Partial View</i></p>

        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.RequestID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "MemberList")
    </div>
}
```

Pages without any details load perfectly, like this

[image]

But pages with corresponding Details, which would trigger the block to `@HTML.Partial()` all throw this ugly error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int16', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CollectionMGR.Models.RequestDetail]'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int16', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CollectionMGR.Models.RequestDetail]'.

Source Error: 

Line 85:     <div>
Line 86:         <p><i>Start of Partial View</i></p>
Line 87:         @Html.Partial("../RequestDetails/DetailsList", Model.RequestID)
Line 88:         <p><i>End of Partial View</i></p>

Line 89: 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int16', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CollectionMGR.Models.RequestDetail]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49
```

I'm so confused!  I can access the DetailsList endpoint all day long, but it crashes when I try to Render Part of it as a Partial view?  Wahhh!

Here's the code for the `RequestDetails/DetailsList` endpoint:

```
@model IEnumerable<CollectionMGR.Models.RequestDetail>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_RequestDetails";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HostName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ResourceID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Request.User)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HostName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResourceID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Request.User)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RequestDetailsID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.RequestDetailsID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RequestDetailsID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("View Request", "../Request/Details/", new { id = item.RequestID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I'm sure the Stack trace is *trying* to be helpful, but I have no idea what it means when talking about conversion of type.  The View I'm trying to Partially Render works perfectly when I navigate to it manually, so I'm not sure why it would fail otherwise.

Thanks for any pointers, I've looked through the other examples for similar topics and just don't get it.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your partial view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<CollectionMGR.Models.RequestDetail>`, but in your main view, you are passing only the `RequestID`.  Make sure you pass the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. Your `DetailsList` view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<CollectionMGR.Models.RequestDetail>`. So it expects a collection of `RequestDetail` objects to be passed to it. But in your code you are calling this view using `Html.Partial` method and passing the `RequestID` property to it, which is an `int` value. You are getting the error because you are passing something different than what it is expecting!

Looking at your code, i see you have an action method `DetailsList`, which gets the data needed for `DetailsList` view and pass to that that view. So in your main view, instead of calling the `Html.Partial` method, you should call the `Html.Action` helper method.

```
<p><i>Start of Partial View(Actually the Action method) </i></p>

@Html.Action("DetailsList",Model.RequestID)

<p><i>End of Partial View</i></p>
```

When razor executes the code of your main view, it will execute this child action `DetailsList` and add the result of that to the main view output.

Comment: Ok, I swapped the code out for that, but now get this error. `
A public action method 'DetailsList' was not found on controller 'CollectionMGR.Controllers.RequestsController'.`  

The Action is from a different controller within my project.  Is there a way I can directly call the other Action from this controller and view?

Comment: Actually I just moved everything into one controller and it works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Which controller has the `DetailsList` defined ? If it is a different action, you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457(v=vs.118).aspx)  where you can specify the action method name and controller name. `@Html.Action("DetailsList","YourOtherControllerName", Model.RequestID)`